# How do I define a math mode formula with a caret ^ in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, macros

This question has two parts.
First, is there a way to define a macro only for math mode?

Second, how do I specifically get the following definition to work correctly?

```
\def\fi{f^{-1}}
```

One additional point is that I'm trying to create this definition within a local scope rather than global scope, but I'm not sure that's relevant.

Comment: Redefining `\fi`, even in a local context, is likely to be a _bad_ idea as it's a TeX primitive used in conditionals.

Comment: For starters you cannot use `\fi` since it declares the end of an `if` statement.

Comment: Good to know. Clearly I'm a neophyte @ TeX. :)

Comment: I think `\newcommand` would be preferred over `\def` ... this applies to all the answers below!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
  \def\fi{f^{-1}}
```

Don't even *think* of redefining `\fi` `\fi` is the TeX primitive (if backwards) that terminates every conditional construct. If you redefine this then more or less every construct in LaTeX will break.

```
  \def\finv{f^{-1}}
```

would define `\finv` to produce f<sup>-1</sup> which is what I assume you want rather than a literal `^` in the printed output?

Comment: In my answer I've added the conditional "unless you are a wizard".  Surely, David, *you* are allowed to redefine `\fi` at will!

Comment: Not `\fi` I'd redefine most things but not that unless you're in a latex3 mood and redefine (undefine) \if and \ifx and \ifmath and friends at the same time

Answer (score 7):

1. You can use `\ifmmode`, e.g. `\def\fim{\ifmmode f^{-1}\fi}`
2. Do not redefine `\fi` unless you are a wizard.  It is used in all `\if..` constructions.  Define `\fim` instead.

Answer (score 5):

For starters `\fi` is a TeX primitive and it declares the end of an `if` statement. To answer your question you can use the `amsmath` package with:

```
\def\finv{\ensuremath{f^{-1}}}
```

This ensures you are in math mode every time. Yet a variant of this using the `fixltx2e` and `xspace` packages you can create the same command by using `\TextOrMath{<text mode>}{<math mode>}`:

```
\newcommand{\finv}{\TextOrMath{$f^{-1}$\xspace}{f^{-1}}}
```